# Can I get the bean name without implementing BeanNameAware?

Tags: java, spring

I have a class instantiated by Spring XML configuration file that currently implements [BeanNameAware](https://docs.spring.io/spring-framework/docs/current/javadoc-api/org/springframework/beans/factory/BeanNameAware.html) in order to know its bean name. That works perfectly, however I've just moved the class into a library that does not have a dependency on the Spring libraries. I don't want to add a Spring dependency to that library, so really I'm looking for a simple way (perhaps in the Xml) to cause `setBeanName()` to be called without implemented the `BeanNameAware` interface and without duplicating the name (in order to set it as a property for example).

Is there any way to do such a thing?

Comment: I don't understand. If the library doesn't use Spring, what is its use of the bean name concept? And where does the Spring XML come into play?

Comment: I have beans generated using spring XML used in a project that uses spring xml configured beans. I've moved those beans into a shared library so that they can be used in other projects that may or may not use spring. That shared library does not have a dependency on spring xml. I'm looking for a way to keep the bean name feature where it is useful without pulling extra dependencies into projects that don't need it.

Comment: It doesn't seem like the bean name is relevant in that non-spring context. I'd create a subclass of the bean that is name aware in the Spring related lib. (Or use composition.)

Comment: @SotiriosDelimanolis Thanks. That was the conclusion I came to as well. I was hoping to avoid it though as having methods getBeanName and setBeanName in the library isn't a problem (and is potentially useful for identifying instances even if not set up through spring) but I can't implement that interface.